# Visual Studio Nuget unable to install any package

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, nuget

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and While trying download even the simplest package, I am getting Following error:

> Error downloading 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' from
>   'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/EntityFramework/6.1.3'. The
>   process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\myUsername\.nuget\packages\entityframework\6.1.3\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll'
>   because it is being used by another process. Time Elapsed:
>   00:01:03.5336627 ========== Finished

Comment: Seems like the file to be updated is locked by another process. Did you try restarting your PC?

Comment: Kill devenv.exe restart VS and try again.

Comment: @HamzaAhmedZia No luck

Comment: @UsmanKhalid try Karun Chetri's answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45050008/visual-studio-2017-professional-unable-to-find-package-at-source/45050299#45050299

Comment: Have you try to close your antivirus software and firewall? Besides, try to close visual studio and delete all the folders in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions that contain a copy of Nuget(of course backup it). http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2013/07/30/upgrading-nuget-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it.aspx/

Comment: @Leo-MSFT Did not work. I had to uninstall the visual studio and then reinstall it to make it work. 3 hours wasted.

Comment: @Usman Khalid,  Glad to know that you finally solved your problem. Although we have not yet found the root cause of the problem, you can write your solution as answer and mark it temporary, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and easier to find the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by uninstalling the visual studio and then reinstall it to make it work. 3 hours wasted.

EDIT:
Again got the error but this time I was lucky. There was one process `VBCSCompiler.exe`. I had to kill it manually using `Window Task Manager` and it starts working. I don't know this will work for others but it worked for me so just sharing it.

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.